# Apache2: how to proxy WebSockets to HTTP/2 backend?

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, proxy, http2

My Node.js [application](https://github.com/flancer64/spa-remote-console) can utilize [HTTP/1](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and [HTTP/2](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html) servers. I have configured Apache2 as a forward proxy to work with the backend in HTTP/1 mode, and everything is working fine:

```
    # Redirect all requests to HTTP/1 server.
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} !upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule    "^/(.*)$"  "http://localhost:3002/$1"  [P]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://localhost:3002/$1" [P,L]
```

However, things went awry when I launched the app in HTTP/2 mode and configured Apache2 to proxy HTTP/2 traffic:

```
    # Redirect all requests to HTTP/2 server.
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} !upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule    "^/(.*)$"  "h2c://localhost:3002/$1"  [P]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://localhost:3002/$1" [P,L]
```

Static files work well with `h2c`, but WebSockets don't work at all.

Loaded modules:

```
# apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_http2_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```